# SQL Server - Need to correct the numbering pattern from ABC 1-1-1 to ABC 001-001-001

Tags: sql-server

So we need to pad with zeros in the customer numbering pattern. The length of the numbers in between the dashes should always be 3. So, first it should find the first space and then find the length of the numbers in between the dashes and if it's less than 3 it should pad with zeros

Ex: XYZ 45-678-2

This should be corrected to XYZ 045-678-002.

Answer (score 0):

```
> **Edit Updated for new patterns**

Declare @YourTable table (ID int,YourField varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'XYZ 45-678-2'),
(2,'XYZ 45-678'),
(3,'DA 1-1'),
(4,'XYZ 123-678-9-234')


--Update @YourTable Set YourField     -- If Satisfied Remove Comment
Select A.*,NewField                   -- If Satisfied Remove This Line
       = Concat(Pos1
              ,Format(Try_Convert(int,Pos2),' 000') 
              ,Format(Try_Convert(int,Pos3),'-000') 
              ,Format(Try_Convert(int,Pos4),'-000') 
              ,Format(Try_Convert(int,Pos5),'-000') 
              ,Format(Try_Convert(int,Pos6),'-000') 
              ,Format(Try_Convert(int,Pos7),'-000') 
              ,Format(Try_Convert(int,Pos8),'-000') 
              ,Format(Try_Convert(int,Pos9),'-000') 
               )
  From  @YourTable A
  Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(50)')
                 From (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(Replace(YourField,' ','-'),'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
              ) B
  Where YourField Like '% %-%'
```

The Updated Results Would Be

```
ID  YourField
1   XYZ 045-678-002
2   XYZ 045-678
3   DA 001-001
4   XYZ 123-678-009-234
```

Comment: Its a value stored in a table so we are trying to fix thru an update script.

Comment: @SQLUser one moment

Comment: @SQLUser Table and Field Name?

Comment: OP should first run a check to ensure that all existing values conform to the expected pattern.  None, for example, with only one `'-'`...

Comment: @MatBailie You are 100% correct.  I'll update my answer

Comment: @SQLUser Updated answer to include a WHERE just in case your data is not formatted as expected

Comment: Thanks John..It does work but fails to update when it has only one dash..

Comment: Thanks John..It does work but fails to update when it has only one dash.. For Ex: We have something like AB 1-1 then it should update it as AP 001-001-001

Comment: If it's AB 1-1 it should be AB 001-001-000

Comment: Is there a way we can add all scenarios

Comment: DA 1-1 would need to reflect DA 001-001-001 ;  XYZ 123-678-9-234 would be XYZ 123-678-009-234

Comment: @SQLUser  OK, that is a different solution.  Next time provide a better representation of your data.   Give me a minute to update

Comment: Thank you very much John. The select statement does work as expected but when I try to put it in an update it fails with a Subquery error

Comment: @SQLUser What is the error - runs clean here, even with some bogus data

Comment: UPDATE <Table_Name>
SET CORRECTED_CUST_NUM = (I put in the Select statement) and it failed

Comment: @SQLUser do you have TWO EQUAL signs now .  All you had to do is replace Set YourField with Set CORRECTED_CUST_NUM  (no equal sign)

Comment: I finally got it to work.. Thank you so much John. I was able to run the update successfully :)]