# How to get a specific part from a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a specific part from string.

In the following example the field `POSITION` contains the `A-` block, the `M-0000000359` block and finally the block to the right of `/`.

What I need now is the full number to the right of `/` and if there is a `,` only the full number up to the comma.

So if the next output of `POSITION` would be `A-M-0000000359/10` or `A-M-0000000359/10,10` then the result I need now is `10` in both cases.

**SQL**

```
SELECT POSITION
  ,SUBSTRING((REPLACE(POSITION, SUBSTRING((POSITION), 1, CHARINDEX('/', (POSITION), 1)), '')), 1, CHARINDEX('/', (POSITION), 0)) AS TRIM_A
  ,SUBSTRING((REPLACE(POSITION, SUBSTRING((POSITION), 1, CHARINDEX('/', (POSITION), 1)), '')), 0, CHARINDEX(',', ((REPLACE(POSITION, SUBSTRING((POSITION), 1, CHARINDEX('/', (POSITION), 1)), ''))), 1)) AS TRIM_B
  ,*
FROM ORDER
```

**Output**

```
POSITION             |TRIM_A|TRIM_B
---------------------|------|------|
A-M-0000000359/1     |1
---------------------|------|------|
A-M-0000000359/1,10  |1,10   1
```

Comment: Your examples show what you want in fixed positions.  Is this true in general?

Comment: The example (SQL & Output) is where I am stuck at the moment. The output you see works, if this does answer your question.

Comment: So what is your question of your current code works?

Comment: No, but how to expand the code, that I can guarantee to get the number to the right of the backslash, and if there is a comma, then only up the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a `CASE` statement then. Change the @position variable to test it out.

```
declare @position varchar(64)= 'A-M-0000000359/1111,10'

select 
    case 
        when patindex('%,%',@position) > 0 
        then substring(substring(@position,CHARINDEX('/',@position) + 1,len(@position) - CHARINDEX('/',@position)),1,patindex('%,%',substring(@position,CHARINDEX('/',@position) + 1,len(@position) - CHARINDEX('/',@position))) - 1)
        else substring(@position,CHARINDEX('/',@position) + 1,len(@position) - CHARINDEX('/',@position))
    end
```

Comment: Thx! But it gives me the last number only (`10`). But it should be based on your example `1`.

Comment: fixed it since you want the first one. try now @oldsport

Comment: Instead of `patindex()`, I would just use `like`.

Comment: Good idea @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a lighter alternative

```
Declare @YourTable table (Position varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('A-M-0000000359/1,10'),
('A-M-0000000359/1'),
('A-M-0000000359')


Select A.*
      ,Trim_A = case when charindex('/',Position)=0 then '' else substring(Position,charindex('/',Position)+1,50) end
      ,Trim_B = case when charindex(',',Position)=0 then '' 
                     else substring(Position,charindex('/',Position)+1,charindex(',',Position)-charindex('/',Position)-1) 
                     end
 From  @YourTable A
```

Returns

```
Position             Trim_A   Trim_B
A-M-0000000359/1,10  1,10     1
A-M-0000000359/1     1  
A-M-0000000359
```

Comment: Kudos for taking the extra step in case there wasn't any /

Comment: @scsimon Just always shocked when the user comes back as says "This works, but I ALSO have this condition.  3 solutions for this guy, each time a another drop of information.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232461/sql-server-need-to-correct-the-numbering-pattern-from-abc-1-1-1-to-abc-001-001/41232574#41232574

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this, I found it very simple and easy to understand that we can simply do it using `CASE`

```
create table #test(block varchar(50))

insert into #test values
('A-M-0000000359/10,11'), ('A-M-0000000359/10')

select substring(block, charindex('/', block)+1, 
    case when charindex(',', block) = 0 then 
        len(block) 
    else 
        (charindex(',', block)-1)-charindex('/', block) 
    end) finalValue
from #test

OUTPUT
----------
finalValue
10
10
```